# Sorting the array with state values in React & JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort rows of a table and change each column given the `sortBy` value in the state.

This is my state:

```
state = {
  columnHeaders: ["Meat", "Protein", "Calories", "Carbohydrates", "Fat"],
  rows: [
    ["chicken breast", "25", "200", "37", "8"],
    ["fried chicken", "45", "450", "21", "16"],
    ["baked fish", "15", "250", "30", "9"]
  ],
  sortedBy: "",
  order: "desc",
  query: "all"
};
```

The function is currently filtering all the columns when only one column header is clicked the `sortBy` is dynamically changing so I'm not sure why the entire array is sorting not just the index

```
const { columnHeaders, rows, query, sortedBy, order } = this.state;

const newRows = query === "all" 
  ? rows
  : rows.filter(row => row[0].includes(query));

const sortedRows = sortedBy === ""
  ? newRows
  : newRows.sort((a, b) => {
   const valueA = a[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)];
   const valueB = b[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)];
    let sortedValue = 0;
    if (valueA < valueB) {
      sortedValue = -1;
    } else if (valueA > valueB) {
      sortedValue = 1;
    }
    if (order === "desc") {
      // if descending order, turn around the sort order
      sortedValue *= -1;
    }
    return sortedValue;
  });
```

This is the map that's rendering the `sortedRows` variable

```
{
  sortedRows.map((row, i) => (
    <TableRow key={`thc-${i}`}>
      <TableItem row={row} />
    </TableRow>
  ));
}
```

[source code](https://github.com/MateenCode/tablesort)

Comment: This happen after initial rendering or after you modify `state` values (like `order`, `sortedBy `,...)? if after modify state, what is the value of `sortedBy `?

Comment: This happens after the state is modified I have onclick function that when the Column is click it grabs the columns name and stores it in sortBy state I would like to use the sortBy in the sort function

Comment: base on your data, each row is array, so the value of `sortedBy` should be index *number* of column like 0,1,2...

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I'm trying to find a way to correlate it maybe something like            const valueA = sortBy === "Meat" ? a[0]: " " ... etc 
                  const valueB =  sortBy === "Meat" ? b[0]: " " ... etc

Comment: how about this `const valueA  = a[columnHeaders.indexOf(sortedBy)]` ?

Comment: Its working! thank you but for some reason its filtering all the columns not just the one thats clicked =(                                                                                
  ScreenShot:                                                        
  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28902787/53856776-5a9f4400-3f88-11e9-987c-4812fab90f3f.png

Comment: It most likely because I'm sorting the entire array when I just should be sorting the single row/index